# Clicking an Angular (ng-mousedown) selection list in IE

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation

Hi all I am trying to automate a form filling process and got stuck in clicking an angular selection list after I logged in to a website. I tried to trigger "click" action in different layer of HTML tag however there is no luck. Can anyone please help?

Here is the HTML element I am struggling:

```
<div class="multi-value autocompleteselect">
    <div class="control-field" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (formElement.messages.length > 0) }" ng-style="{'background-color':enableSelect?'':'#ededed'}">
        <div class="dropdown-input" id="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (formElement.messages.length > 0) }" ng-click="enableSelect&amp;&amp;changeFocus()">
            <div class="search">
                <!-- <pre class='pre-input' ng-bind="hoverValue" ></pre> -->
                <label class="control-label hidden" aria-label="Select your country " for="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-input">
                    <span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="formElement.label">Select your country </span>
                </label>
                <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" id="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-input" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" ng-class='{"hide-text":enableSelect&amp;&amp;onHover}' ng-keydown="keyDown($event)" ng-model="dataValue" ng-blur="enableSelect&amp;&amp;checkOptionSelect()" ng-readonly="!enableSelect" ng-focus="enableSelect&amp;&amp;onChange(dataValue);" ng-change="enableSelect&amp;&amp;onChange(dataValue)" ng-style="{'background-color':enableSelect?'':'#ededed'}">
                <!--ng-blur="checkOption()"-->
                <span class="spanDropdown-input" id="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-spanDropdown-input">
                        <i class="icon icon-chevron-up-small" id="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-icon" ng-class="{'icon-chevron-up-small':optionsArray.length > 0 ,'icon-chevron-down-small':optionsArray.length == 0}"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-ul" id="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Container" ng-show="enableSelect&amp;&amp;optionsArray.length > 0">
            <ul>
                <!-- ngRepeat: option in optionsArray --><li class="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Option-0" ng-class='{"selected" : $index === currentIndex}' ng-repeat="option in optionsArray" ng-mousedown="setOption(option, $event)" ng-mouseout="resetHover(option)" ng-mouseover="setHover(option)">
                    <span class="ng-binding" role="option" ng-bind-html="option.displayText">Japan </span>
                </li><!-- end ngRepeat: option in optionsArray --><li class="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Option-1" ng-class='{"selected" : $index === currentIndex}' ng-repeat="option in optionsArray" ng-mousedown="setOption(option, $event)" ng-mouseout="resetHover(option)" ng-mouseover="setHover(option)">
                    <span class="ng-binding" role="option" ng-bind-html="option.displayText">South Korea</span>
                </li><!-- end ngRepeat: option in optionsArray --><li class="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Option-2" ng-class='{"selected" : $index === currentIndex}' ng-repeat="option in optionsArray" ng-mousedown="setOption(option, $event)" ng-mouseout="resetHover(option)" ng-mouseover="setHover(option)">
                    <span class="ng-binding" role="option" ng-bind-html="option.displayText">Taiwan</span>
                …..
                </li><!-- end ngRepeat: option in optionsArray --><li class="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Option-250" ng-class='{"selected" : $index === currentIndex}' ng-repeat="option in optionsArray" ng-mousedown="setOption(option, $event)" ng-mouseout="resetHover(option)" ng-mouseover="setHover(option)">
                    <span class="ng-binding" role="option" ng-bind-html="option.displayText">Zimbabwe</span>
                </li><!-- end ngRepeat: option in optionsArray -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Excel VBA code below, I am able to get to the correct layer by checking the layer class name / ID however still unable to trigger click action on the list item:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDropdownOption As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDropdownOption2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDropdownOption3 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLDropdownOption4 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
HTMLDoc.parentWindow.Focus
Set HTMLDropdownOption = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-ul")(0)
'Got to <UL> layer
Set HTMLDropdownOption2 = HTMLDropdownOption.ChildNodes(1)
HTMLDropdownOption2.SetFocus
HTMLDropdownOption2.Click
'Go to <li> layer, class="P77-C2-C3-C8-C8-C8-F1-Dropdown-Option-0"
Set HTMLDropdownOption3 = HTMLDropdownOption2.ChildNodes(2)
HTMLDropdownOption3.Focus        
HTMLDropdownOption3.Click
'Go to <span> layer, class="ng-binding"
Set HTMLDropdownOption4 = HTMLDropdownOption3.ChildNodes(1)
HTMLDropdownOption4.Focus        
HTMLDropdownOption4.Click
```